# How to transfer a file type from Coldfusion code to javascript code?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I'm a newbie to ColdFusion, I got a problem when I used a file type data in the embedded js code. I got a uploaded file from the FORM. Below is the form code.

```
        <cfform name='uploadForm' action='#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post' onsubmit='loading()'>
            <input type='hidden' name='trigger' value='yes' />
            <input type='hidden' name='file_type' id='file_type' />
            <input type='hidden' name='presentation_id' id='presentation_id' />
            <input type='hidden' name='productionYear' id='productionYear' />
            <div><input type='file' name='fileToUpload' size='45' id="uploadID" onChange="setFile();"></div>

            <div class='loading' id='loading' style='display: none'>
                <img src='buttons/load_bar.gif' />
                <div>The file is uploading. Please do not click anything or make changes to the media form.</div>
            </div>
            <div class='empty' id='empty' style='display: block'>
            </div>
            <div><input type='submit' value='Upload File' class='submit'></div>
        </cfform>
```

next is my function to get the submitted file:

```
<cfscript>
function getClientFileName(fieldName) {
    var tmpPartsArray = Form.getPartsArray();
    var clientFileName = "";

    if (IsDefined("tmpPartsArray")) {
        for (local.tmpPart in tmpPartsArray) {
            if (local.tmpPart.isFile() AND local.tmpPart.getName() EQ arguments.fieldName) {
                return local.tmpPart;
            }
        }
    }

    return "";
}

</cfscript>
```

I used a `<cfset clientFileName = getClientFileName("fileTOUpload")>` to get the file data.

Then in my javascript code:

```
var result = client.media.upload(cb, '#clientFileName#');
```

the second argument here should be a file type. But the upload failed with the error the second argument is not a file type data.

SO anybody could tell me what should I do here? thanks in advance.

Comment: If you view the source of the page, what is `#clientFileName#` appearing as?

Comment: Welcome to CFML!  First thing, I would change <cfform to just <form.  <cfform and its sibbling tags are legacy and should be avoided.

Comment: Now, to your question, make sure the parts of your JS that will render CFML expressions/variables is wrapped in <cfoutput>

Comment: Why are you using javascript at all when it's so easy to upload a file with ColdFusion's `<cffile>` tag?

Comment: "clientFileName" appears to be 'null'. Because I have to use a js API to upload the file to a certain platform, hope you understand.

Comment: Which API are you using?

Comment: kaltura, a video platform, I want to create an entry for people to upload video files to its console.

Comment: Just trying to understand the process - you are uploading a file to your CFML server, which then returns back to the browser with javascript to re-upload the file using client.media.upload()?

Answer (score 4):

Commented before, but here's an example.  To render CFML variables the CFML must be inside a `<cfoutput></cfoutput>` block. So in your case you want the result from `clientFileName` to render inside the JS.  Now, assuming your JS is inside a .cfm page, it could look like this:

```
<cfoutput>
<script>
   var result = client.media.upload(cb, '#clientFileName#');
</script>
</cfoutput>
```

Or if it's just #clientFileName# you need to render you could just wrap that:

```
<script>
   var result = client.media.upload(cb, '<cfoutput>#clientFileName#</cfoutput>');
</script>
```

Just remember that anytime you need to output data using #'s you need to be inside a `<cfoutput>` block.

Comment: I did render the variable in <cfoutput></cfoutput>, the problem now is the javascript function does not think '#clientFileName#' is a file type, thus "null" will be in the second parameter, the output will fail.

Comment: What does that line of JS look like when you view source? does it still show '#clientFileName#'? If it does then ColdFusion isn't rendering it.  Another help would be to place <cfdump var="#clientFileName#"> after you set clientFileName to see what the variable value should be.

Comment: If I am reading correctly, I am sure your javascript code makes sense ... The CF variable containing the file name is not available until *after* the file is uploaded, so you cannot use it in javascript code *before* the upload ie `client.media.upload(..)`. The variable won't exist yet.

Comment: Gah, that should read "I am **not** sure your javascript code makes sense..".  ie Seems like you may be confusing server and client side code.

Comment: I think you are right. So how can I get the file to be uploaded? just use the document.getElementsById()?

Comment: Yes, that should give you the current value of the input field.

Comment: @KevinZhu - BTW, though cfscript looks similar to javascript, it is very different. It is server side code: see [CFML request/response process](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/10/the-coldfusion-requestresponse-process.html).

Comment: Good call @Leigh, I was assuming the js was in an "action" cfm page.